# Multiple values over more than one column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a speadsheet with information that looks like this:

**Sheet 1**

```
Column A             Column B    
Name    
Daniel
```

**Sheet 2**

```
Column A             Column B             Column C
Name                 Yes/No               Number 
Daniel               No                   39501
```

Is there a formula for making sure that the names on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are "True", and that they match, and that if column B on Sheet 2 comes back as "No", then the value that is in column C on Sheet 2 is represented in column B of Sheet 1? I think ideally the formula would be found in column B of Sheet 1.

Any further information, please don't hesitate to get in contact.

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: What do you mean with `the names on Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 are "True"`?

Comment: There probably is.  But I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and then edit your question to show us what you have tried, and where you have run into a problem.

Comment: Hi David - I mean do they match one another, Is the name on Sheet 1 Column A the same as Sheet 2 Column A.

Comment: read about `IF` and `VLOOKUP`functions.

Comment: Hi Ron - I have used everything from if statements, to vlookups. The problem I am having is that if I have multiple data in sheet 1 and multiple date in sheet 2 how do i like the names up with "Yes/ No" statement and the "Number" column in Sheet 2, with Column B in Sheet 1.

Comment: Hi Ron - I suppose in terms of formulas I have tried: =IF(A2=Sheet2!A2,Sheet2!C2,IF(Sheet2!B:B="No",,C2)), and it has returned Column C in Sheet 2, however, if I have multiple lines in any of the columns in Sheet 2, it returns either an "N/A" or a "Value"

Comment: I'm still having a problem understanding exactly what you are trying to do.  I suggest you create an example that shows your problem, and **edit your question** to show that information and clarify your problem.  (Don't do it in the comments; much harder to read and put together). You should also read the HELP for information as to how to notify others that you have directed a comment towards them.  I only found these 6 hour old comments directed to me by chance.  And, in your example, you have one name on sheet 1 and the same name on Sheet2.  Surely you can provide a more extensive example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is what you are looking for - formula in B2 to B4

```
=IF(INDEX(E$2:E$4,MATCH(A2,D$2:D$4,0))="No",INDEX(F$2:F$4,MATCH(A2,D$2:D$4,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this will also work. paste formula in B2 cell on sheet1

=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)="No",VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE),"")